# How to define a url range for a Grails plugin

Tags: grails

I have a Grails app that should be extended by more than one own implemented Grails plugins. I import them in the *BuildConfig.groovy* just like other plugins.

The Controller of each plugin can be called under the root url:

```
http://localhost/application/<ctrlPlugin1>
http://localhost/application/<ctrlPlugin1>/<endpoint1>
http://localhost/application/<ctrlPlugin2>
```

At this moment the controller names in plugin1 must be different than in plugin2.

How can I define a url range, so that all endpoints of a plugin are under a special url path and the controller names in the plugins can be equal?

```
http://localhost/application/<plugin1>/<ctrlPlugin1>
http://localhost/application/<plugin1>/<ctrlPlugin1>/<endpoint1>
http://localhost/application/<plugin2>/<ctrlPlugin2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [controller namespaces](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Controllers/namespace.html) to achieve something like this by adding `static namespace = 'ctrlPlugin1'` in every controller of the corresponding plugin.

Another way of achieving this would be to create a `CrtlPluginXUrlMappings.groovy` that maps their corresponding controllers under a certain base path like so:

```
class CrtlPluginXUrlMappings {
  "/crtlPluginX/customers" resources: "customer"
  "/crtlPluginX/orders" resources: "order"
}
```